# Remove characters from a string then reverse it

Tags: javascript, string, function, reverse

I need a function that takes a characters array and returns the same array but reversed and without the "*" character.

I have tried a lot of codes without success. This was my last attempt (sorry if doesn't have sense, I am learning JS)

```
function laClaveSecreta(carac){
    let new_str=[];
    for(i=0;i<carac.length;i++){
        if(carac[i]==="*"){
            new_str=new_str.push(carac.replace(/[*\s]/g, ''));
            
        }
        return new_str.reverse();
    }
    
 
}

//Running the function with this parameter

laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] )

//Result I am looking for

"El día es lunes"
```

Comment: it would be easier to convert the array to a string first, then you can use `replace` on the entire string. `carac.reverse().join("").replace(/[*]/g, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to convert the array to a string first, then you can use replace on the entire string -

```js
const input =
  [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"]

console.log(input.reverse().join("").replace(/[*]/g, ""))
```

```
El día es lunes
```

This isn't going to teach you much though. I assume this is a homework assignment or something. Using built-in functions like `reverse`, `join`, and `replace` are higher-level. You can solve the problem using a very basic `for` loop -

```js
function laClaveSecreta(carac)
{ let r = ""
  for (const c of carac)
    if (c == "*")
      continue
    else
      r = c + r
  return r
}

const input =
  [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"]

console.log(laClaveSecreta(input))
```

```
El día es lunes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `let filteredArray = carac.filter( char => char != '*')` then `return filteredArray.reverse().join("")`

Answer (score 0):

I have filtered the array, reversed it and then I joined it without regex. The code looks cleaner and explains the steps.

```
const laClaveSecreta = (arr) => arr.filter(arrItem => arrItem !== '*').reverse().join('');

laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] )
```

Comment: why bother checking `arr.length`? `filter`, `reverse` and `join` also work on empty arrays. why bother with variable assignment `newStr` when you can just write `return arr.filter(...)...` instead?

Comment: Just an old habit to make code readable and fail-proof but good suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const input =
  [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"]

console.log(input.reverse().filter(item => item !== "*").join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that  this way...

```js
const laClaveSecreta  = carac =>
  {
  let new_str = '';
  for(i=carac.length;i--;)
    if(carac[i]!=="*") new_str +=carac[i]
  return new_str 
  }

console.log( laClaveSecreta('s*enul s*e aí*d l*E*'))
```

or

```js
const laClaveSecreta  = carac => carac.reduceRight((a,c)=> (c==="*") ? a : a+c ,'')

console.log( laClaveSecreta([...'s*enul s*e aí*d l*E*']))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function laClaveSecreta(carac){
  let new_str=[];
  for(i=0;i<carac.length;i++){
    if(carac[i] !=="*"){
        new_str.push(carac[i]);
    }
}
 return new_str.reverse();
}
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.